# Cartopy projection changing with different data / unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am migrating from basemap to cartopy so I'm still trying to find the ropes! If I plot some data on a projection, I would expect it to plot the map then the data on top, like this

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

latitude = np.linspace(-90, 90, 180)
longitude = np.linspace(-180,180,360)
data = np.cos(np.deg2rad(latitude[:, np.newaxis])) + np.sin(np.deg2rad(longitude))
crs = ccrs.Orthographic(-30,45) #some sample data

ax1 = plt.subplot(121,projection=crs)
ax1.contourf(longitude, latitude,data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.coastlines('110m', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.75)
```

This will produce a true orographic projection with the data. But if I make some of the data void/nan, it no longer plots over the same domain:

```
data[0:150,:] = np.nan

ax1 = plt.subplot(122,projection=crs)
ax1.contourf(longitude, latitude,data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.coastlines('110m', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.75)

plt.show()
```

From basemap, I would expect the same domain to be plotted, but where data is nan it would just be white. How do I force cartopy to stop 'auto-adjusting' to the data, and to keep the same projection?

Image of how `data[0:150,:] = np.nan` affects the projection below.
Thanks in advance! I tried to force it with `ax1.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], ccrs.PlateCarree())` but to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cartopy always tries to fit the domain to the data extents. If you want to see a global plot the use `ax1.set_global()` to force this:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

latitude = np.linspace(-90, 90, 180)
longitude = np.linspace(-180,180,360)
data = np.cos(np.deg2rad(latitude[:, np.newaxis])) + np.sin(np.deg2rad(longitude))
crs = ccrs.Orthographic(-30,45) #some sample data

ax1 = plt.subplot(121,projection=crs)
ax1.contourf(longitude, latitude,data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.coastlines('110m', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.75)

data[0:150,:] = np.nan

ax1 = plt.subplot(122,projection=crs)
ax1.contourf(longitude, latitude,data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.coastlines('110m', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.75)
ax1.set_global()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn’t notice this in the API!